# Remove Items from a struct array

Tags: arrays, c, struct

So I'm implementing a TCP server chatroom in C and using poll to handle multiple clients. Users register with a username and password and then Login with it. When they login I want to add them to this struct array.

```
struct onlineUsers{
int sockfd;
char username[9]; //usernames size is maximum 8 characters
};

struct onlineUsers users[10];

//The login function is pretty long so is here the relevant part.
    if(!searchExist(search, db)){
        printf("Account doesnt exist.\n");
        fclose(db);
        free(search);
        return -1;
    }
    else{
        printf("Logged in\n");
        // Add to onlineUser struct arr[]
    }
```

But when the client closes the connection how would you remove that specific element from the onlineUsers array? I haven't implemented the way to add them since I don't really have a good way to remove them.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].  What is "this struct". There are two shown. "*how would you remove that specific element from the onlineUsers struct*". You don't remove from a struct. You presumably have a list of those structs and you should be removing from the list. We need to see what type of list it is and how you have added to it.

Comment: How are you keeping track of how many users there are?

Comment: Also, what are `search` and `db` and how are they related to `users`?

Comment: ....or, just provide a [mcve] which answers all these details.

Comment: you can add a field `bool online` to `struct onlineUsers`

Comment: So basically I write the usernames and passwords to a file and use the searchExists to see if its in the file. If the username/password exist the user is logged in and then I want to add them to the users array. I'm trying to use this array to keep track of "logged in" users. If this doesn't seem optimal I'm open to new ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reworked this into a minimal example and implemented a linear search for you (use `lfind` in `remove_user()` and `lsearch` in `add_user()` if available):

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NAME 8
#define MAX_USERS 2

struct user {
    char name[MAX_NAME + 1];
};

unsigned find_pos(struct user *users, const char *name) {
    unsigned empty = MAX_USERS;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_USERS; i++) {
       if(empty == MAX_USERS && !users[i].name[0]) empty = i;
       if(!strcmp(users[i].name, name)) return i;
    }
    return empty;
}

int add_user(struct user *users, const char *name) {
    unsigned pos = find_pos(users, name);
    if(pos == MAX_USERS) return -1;
    if(users[pos].name[0]) return 1;
    // safe as name[8] is 0 initialized; otherwise
    // copy MAX_NAME + 1 then set name[MAX_NAME] = '\0'
    // to ensure string is \0 terminated.
    strncpy(users[pos].name, name, MAX_NAME);
    return 0;
}

int remove_user(struct user *users, const char *name) {
    int pos = find_pos(users, name);
    if(!users[pos].name[0] || strcmp(users[pos].name, name)) return 1;
    users[pos].name[0] = '\0';
    return 0;
}


int main() {
    struct user users[MAX_USERS] = { 0 };
    assert(add_user(users, "bob") == 0); // ok (1 of 2)
    assert(add_user(users, "bob") == 1); // duplicate
    assert(remove_user(users, "bob") == 0); // ok (empty)
    assert(remove_user(users, "jane") == 1); // non-existing
    assert(add_user(users, "bob") == 0); // ok (1 of 2)
    assert(add_user(users, "jane") == 0); // ok (2 of 2)
    assert(add_user(users, "jack") == -1); // full
    assert(remove_user(users, "bob") == 0); // ok
    assert(find_pos(users, "jane") == 1); // ok (not empty slot)
}
```

Comment: " users[i].name[0] && strcmp(users[i].name, name)" what do these conditions do?

Comment: The idea is that user `i` is deleted by setting `users[i].name` to the empty string which in C you by setting the first character of the string to `'\0'`.  The expression here was meant to return the index of either the first empty slot or matching user.  Upon further reflection this is actually incorrect and I changed the code.  We have to look through all users to see if any of them match, and if not then return an empty slot. You can do it with two loops, or as here, remember one of the empty slots.

Comment: How does  ```if(users[pos].name[0]) return 1;```  in add_user satisfy as a condition and what does it do?

Comment: `users[pos]` is non-empty which means `name` was already in the list (as we handle the full case above).  It's much faster to try things than asking me.  For instance if you remove the line what test case(s) fail?

Comment: I see It checks for duplicates. Thanks for the help it really tied things together for me.